# iPad display configured landscape but acting like portrait - cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, landscape

I developed a hybrid mobile application for tablets/iPads. Everything is good with Android. But with iPads the display which is configured as landscape acts like a portrait so we have a stretched and cut screens. (height should be 768px and not 1024px).

Comment: @Andrei M Have you had any answer to this. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114845/ipad-landscape-has-empty-space-at-bottom-after-device-768px-height, this solves the height issue but the buttom has the space ...